# Rails 4 where and take methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

This is for a shopping cart:

I have two models, PromoCode and PromoRule.

In the PromoCode model I want to search all PromoRule records and if the promo_code attribute in the PromoCode model matches one of the PromoRule records, I want to assign that PromoRule to the PromoCode.

I'm trying to find the matching PromoRule doing this:

```
 @promo_rule = PromoRule.where(["rule_code = ?", self.promo_code]).take
```

Then assign the promo_rule id to the promo_code doing this:

```
self.promo_rule_id = @promo_rule
```

This does not work either:

```
self.promo_rule_id = @promo_rule
```

**When I enter a promo code and submit, it updates the PromoCode. At that time, the update_promo_code method gets executed.  I'm not getting any errors but the promo rule id does not get associated with the promo code. 
Any suggestions?**

**promo_code.rb**

```
class PromoCode < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :order
    belongs_to  :promo_rule
    before_update :update_promo_code


    def update_promo_code
        if self.promo_code.present?
            @promo_rule = PromoRule.where(["rule_code = ?", self.promo_code]).take
            self.promo_rule_id = @promo_rule
            self.apply_promo = true
        end
    end

end
```

promo_rule.rb

```
class PromoRule < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :promo_codes
end
```

Comment: You should probably explain what is 'not working' -- by including an error log, stack trace, etc.

Comment: Question updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. It was so simple.

in the PromoCode model's update_promo_code method
changed this:
**self.promo_rule*_id* = @promo_rule**

to this:
**self.promo_rule = @promo_rule**